# Updating Score Pygame Pong

Tags: python, pygame, pong

For whatever reason, the score display in my pong game is not updating. It just keeps saying "0". I checked to see if the score was actually being updated in the logic of the game and it is (printed it out to console). I have the text being "blitted" every time a new display is drawn so can anyone tell me why it won't update?

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

# Create colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Create screen and set screen caption
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

# Loop until user clicks close button
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen is updated
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create player class
class Player():

    # Initialize player paddles
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, height, width):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.y_speed = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 24, True, False)
        self.display_score = self.font.render("Score: %d " % (self.score), True, WHITE)

    # Updates with new position of paddle every frame
    def draw(self, y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, y, self.height, self.width])

    # Keeps paddle from going off screen
    def keepOnScreen(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
        elif self.y > 410:
            self.y = 410

# Create Ball class
class Ball():

    # Initialize ball in the middle of the screen with no movement
    def __init__(self, color, height, width):
        self.x = 325
        self.y = random.randrange(150, 350)
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.y_speed = 0
        self.x_speed = 0

    # Updates new position of ball every frame
    def draw(self, x, y):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [x, y, self.height, self.width])

# Create instances of both players and ball
player1 = Player(50, 100, WHITE, 25, 90)
player2 = Player(625, 100, WHITE, 25, 90)   
ball = Ball(WHITE, 20, 20)

# --- Main Program Loop --- 
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # We are done so we exit this loop

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # Players utilize keyboard to move paddles
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player1.y_speed = -6
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player2.y_speed = -6
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player1.y_speed = 6
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player2.y_speed = 6
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: # Starts the ball movement
                ball.x_speed = 3 * random.randrange(-1, 1, 2)
                ball.y_speed = 3 * random.randrange(-1, 1, 2)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player1.y_speed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player2.y_speed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player1.y_speed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player2.y_speed = 0

    # Calculate the movement of the players
    player1.y += player1.y_speed
    player2.y += player2.y_speed

    # Prevents paddles from going off-screen
    player1.keepOnScreen()
    player2.keepOnScreen()

    # Checks to see if ball has made contact with paddle, then reverses direction of the ball
    # Had to give a 4 pixel buffer since the ball won't always exactly hit the same part of paddle in x direction
    if ball.x <= player1.x + 27 and (ball.x >= player1.x + 23):
        if ball.y >= player1.y and (ball.y <= player1.y + 100):
            ball.x_speed *= -1  
    if ball.x >= player2.x - 27 and (ball.x <= player2.x - 23):
        if ball.y >= player2.y and (ball.y <= player2.y + 100):
            ball.x_speed *= -1

    # Checks to see if ball has made contact with top or bottom of screen
    if ball.y <= 0 or ball.y >= 480:
        ball.y_speed *= -1

    # Calculates movement of the ball
    ball.x += ball.x_speed
    ball.y += ball.y_speed

    # Updates score
    if ball.x < 0:
        player2.score += 1
        ball.__init__(WHITE, 20, 20)

    if ball.x > 700:
        player1.score += 1
        ball.__init__(WHITE, 20, 20)

    # Set background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw players and ball on screen
    player1.draw(player1.y)
    player2.draw(player2.y)
    ball.draw(ball.x, ball.y)
    screen.blit(player1.display_score, [0, 0])
    screen.blit(player2.display_score, [615, 0])

    # Update display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you're setting each player's `display_score` only in their `__init__` function.

```
# Initialize player paddles
def __init__(self, x, y, color, height, width):
    ...
    self.score = 0
    ...
    self.display_score = self.font.render("Score: %d " % (self.score), True, WHITE)
```

Because of the way you initialize the variable, changing the value of `player.score` does not change the value of `player.display_score`.

**Solution 1**

You could change the value of `display_score` when you change the player scores, which would be easily done through a function call:

```
def player_scores( player, ball ):
    player.score += 1
    player.display_score = player.font.render("Score: %d " % (player.score), True, WHITE)
    ball.__init__(WHITE, 20, 20)
```

Then in your game loop:

```
# Updates score
if ball.x < 0:
    player_scores( player2, ball )

if ball.x > 700:
    player_scores( player1, ball )
```

**Solution 2**

You could render the score text when you display it, rather than creating it on the players. In your game loop:

```
    screen.blit(player1.font.render("Score: %d " % (player1.score), True, WHITE), [0, 0])
    screen.blit(player2.font.render("Score: %d " % (player2.score), True, WHITE), [615, 0])
```

This invalidates the `display_score` variable completely

Comment: Thanks. I get now how the solutions are correct/make more sense, but can you elaborate more on why player.display_score never changes but player.score does? If I am updating player.score down further in the program how come it doesn't change in player.display_score? Is it because player.displace_score is in the init function?

Comment: When you format a string, it takes the values of the parameters used to format it, not a reference to them. Therefore, it only looks at the value of `score` when you format it, and has no way of knowing if score changed or even where it is in memory. It's also important to remember that strings are immutable, which means that you can't modify them once they're created, you have to make a whole new string.